# R: scraping authors name from table of contents of Sage journal

Tags: r, rvest

I’m trying to scrape the table of content of a journal published by Sage. Scraping titles and URLs is a no brainer. Scraping author names is tricky though, maybe because they open a pop-up with lots of information (affiliation, orcid, etc.), and SelectorGadget seems unable to decipher between all these.
After several attempts, the following code:

```
author_1 <- read_html("https://journals.sagepub.com/toc/ossa/40/1") %>%
  html_nodes('.all') %>%
  html_text(trim = TRUE)
author_1
```

gives:

> [1] "Andrew D. Brown Andrew D. BrownUniversity of Bath, UK View ORCID
> profileSee all articles by this author\nSearch Google Scholar\n for
> this author"
> [2] "Peter Fleming Peter FlemingSee all articles by this
> author\nSearch Google Scholar\n for this author"
> [3] "Mike Reed Mike ReedCardiff Business School, UKSee all articles by
> this author\nSearch Google Scholar\n for this author,  Gibson Burrell
> Gibson BurrellUniversities of Leicester and Manchester, UK View ORCID
> profileSee all articles by this author\nSearch Google Scholar\n for
> this author"

etc.

Regex to clean this is beyond my limited skills (especially since some articles, like the 3rd one, have several authors).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it is already sufficient to use `str_split()` or similar to split the strings using "View ORCID ... Search Google ... for this Author" as separator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can identify the parent nodes and then map over these to return a list that keeps the authors together:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

page <- read_html("https://journals.sagepub.com/toc/ossa/40/1")

page %>%
  html_nodes('div.tocAuthors') %>%
  map(~ html_nodes(.x, 'div.header a.entryAuthor') %>%
      html_text(trim = TRUE))

[[1]]
[1] "Andrew D. Brown"

[[2]]
[1] "Peter Fleming"

[[3]]
[1] "Mike Reed"      "Gibson Burrell"

...
```

Or for a single string of authors per article:

```
page %>%
  html_nodes('div.tocAuthors') %>%
  map_chr(~ html_nodes(.x, 'div.header a.entryAuthor') %>%
         html_text(trim = TRUE) %>% toString)

 [1] "Andrew D. Brown"                              "Peter Fleming"                               
 [3] "Mike Reed, Gibson Burrell"                    "Joep Cornelissen"                            
 [5] "Silviya Svejenova"                            "Mélodie Cartel, Eva Boxenbaum, Franck Aggeri"
 [7] "Deborah N. Brewis"                            "Renate Ortlieb, Barbara Sieben"              
 [9] "Lynne Andersson, Dirk Lindebaum, Mar Pérezts" "Lidia Greco"                                 
[11] "Michael Rowlinson"                            "Andrew Crane"                                
[13] "Jean Jenkins"
```